# Overlay controls in an Image that adjusts depending on the device's Resolution/DPI

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, overlay

Taking a Rufus Image as an example, i'm looking for a way to overlay an actual (Xamarin.Forms) Button on top of a Rufus Button based on the image. I am able to achieve such via `AbsoluteLayout` by specifying the `LayoutBounds` while `LayoutFlags` is set to `All`.

However, the the `LayoutBounds` obviously change based on the device's screen resolution so an accurate positioning on one device means inaccurate on the other. Is there any other way of achieving this aside from `AbsoluteLayout` while also being able to adapt on different screen sizes?

I was thinking `Grid` and using many many `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions` until i get a small size boxed which I can then `Span` the `Rows` or `Columns` depending on where Rufus Button would end up. But that would be messy and hacking over a solution that might already be existing and is cleaner and better.

Xaml Code:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <Image Source="https://i.ibb.co/vQbZ3bH/1.jpg"
           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />

    <!-- SELECT Button-->
    <Button Opacity=".5"
            BackgroundColor="Red"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.963,0.304,0.2,0.03"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            Clicked="Button_Clicked" />

    <!--- START Button -->
    <Button Opacity=".5"
            BackgroundColor="Red"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.681,0.814,0.2,0.03"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            Clicked="Button_Clicked" />

    <!--- CLOSE Button -->
    <Button Opacity=".5"
            BackgroundColor="Red"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.963,0.814,0.2,0.03"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

UI Result on Phone A (Accurate):
[image]

UI Result on Phone B (Inaccurate):
[image]

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT hmm, i never actually tried `RelativeLayout` **yet** because the documentation tells me to **avoid it** lol. but i'll give it a try because based on your description, it might actually be what i'm looking for. thanks!

Comment: Oh, and uh, any chance you can move your comment as an answer? so i can tag it as the answer i'm looking for if it works for my case? Cheers!

Comment: Yes,of course .

Answer (score 0):

You could use [RelativeLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relativelayout).It is used to position and size children relative to properties of the layout or sibling elements. This allows UIs to be created that scale proportionally across device sizes